# Generalized Tube Lemma

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. And let $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$ be closed subspaces. If $U$ is open in $X \times Y$ and $U$ contains $A \times B$, then there exists open subsets $V \subset X$ and $W \subset Y$ such that $A \times B \subset V \times W \subset U$.

I think this is an easier version of the generalized tube lemma since it assumes $X$ and $Y$ being Hausdorff, but I just can't seem to find such $V$ and $W$. I can find some open set in $X \times Y$ containing $A \times B$ but not able to show it is contained in $U$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(this is called the Wallace theorem/lemma in Engelking IIRC; there is a version for infinite products too, and Hausdorffness is not needed).

For each $a \in A$ and each $b \in B$ pick $V(a,b) \subseteq X$ open and $W(a,b) \subseteq Y$ open such that $$ (a,b) \in V(a,b) \times W(a,b) \subseteq U$$ which can be done as open squares form a base for the product topology. Now we go in two steps, exploiting both sets' compactness in turn.

Fix $b \in B$ for now, and note that $V(a,b)$, $a \in A$ forms an open cover of the compact $A$, so there are finitely many $F_b \subseteq A$ such that $V(b)=\cup_{a \in F_b} V(a,b)$ covers $A$ while $W(b) = \bigcap_{a \in F_b} V(a,b)$ is a neighbourhood of $b$. This defines open sets $V(b)\supseteq A$ of $X$ and open neighbourhoods $W(b)$ of $b$ such that $$V(b)\times W(b) \subseteq U$$.

Now the $W(b)$  cover $B$, also compact, so finitely many, say $\{W(b): b \in H\}$ cover $B$, where $H \subseteq B$ is finite. Now define $V = \bigcap_{b \in H} V(b)$ and $W=\bigcup_{b \in H} W(b)$ and note that

$$A \times B \subseteq V \times W \subseteq U$$ as required.

It's just applying the idea of the tube lemma twice, really.

The proof only needs $A$ and $B$ to be compact, and nothing on $X$ and $Y$. So your textbook misses an easy generalisation here.

Comment: Are there some typos here? Where is the $U(a,b)$ coming from? And each $V(b)$ covers $A$ while the union over $b\in B$ of the $W(b)$ cover $B$.Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Matematleta $U$ is pregiven.

Comment: No. I mean the $U(a,b)$

Comment: @Matematleta I chose the $V(a,b)$ at the start.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a normal space, and $A\subseteq X\cap U$, which is open in $X$ so there is a $V$ open in $X$ such that $A\subseteq V\subseteq \overline V\subseteq  X\cap U.$ Similarly, there is a $W$ open in $Y$ such that $B\subseteq W\subseteq \overline W\subseteq  Y\cap U.$ Then, $A\times B\subseteq V\times W\subseteq (X\cap U)\times (Y\cap U)=U.$

Comment: $O \subseteq \pi_X[U]$ and $O' \subseteq \pi_Y[U]$ does not necessarily imply $O \times O' \subseteq U$.

Comment: Right ugh I need to fix this thanks!